# Get current page name with JSF/PrettyFaces

Tags: java, jsf-2, url-rewriting, prettyfaces

i am using PrettyFaces as url rewrite library as follows:

```
@URLMappings(mappings = {
        @URLMapping(id = "page1", pattern = "/page1", viewId = "/faces/pages/page1.xhtml"),
        @URLMapping(id = "page2", pattern = "/page2", viewId = "/faces/pages/page2.xhtml") })
```

i can get the viewId as follows:

```
String viewId = facesContext.getViewRoot().getViewId();
```

which will return something like: **/faces/pages/page1.xhtml**

i was wondering if there's a direct way to get the pattern or the id of the view to return something like **page1** or i have to use **substring** on the above code for getting the viewId?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yep :) Just call:

```
PrettyContext.getCurrentInstance().getCurrentMapping().getId();
```

or, `.getPattern()` or etc...

Cheers :)

Comment: is it possible to get the mapping id in the xhtml page ?